# “Incomplete or corrupt PNG file” when adding image to a PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a PNG image that I want to display in a PDF. But when I use following code I get this error:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file
Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file
```

This is my code:

```
let image = "assets/img/bgconfidential.png";
let img = new Image();
img.style.opacity = '0.2';
img.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=20)';
img.src = image;
console.log(img);
doc.addImage(img, 'png', internalPageWidth - 140 , 100, 20, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library, but [according to the documentation](https://mrrio.github.io/), you have to actually pass image data to `addImage`.

There are a couple ways to handle this.  One is to take the `Image` instance, draw it to a canvas, encode the canvas bitmap data as a PNG, and then encode the PNG output to base64.  That's what the documentation says to do.

There is another way.  You can use the Fetch API.  Untested, but something like:

```
fetch('/assets/img/bgconfidential.png')
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      doc.addImage(reader.result, 'png', ...);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
```